# Keyboard is shown even edittextview is enable false

Tags: android, keyboard

To show keyboard on activity open i have set the android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" in manifest file.

On wrong attempt of authentication, I set password.setEnable(false) so, opened keyboard disappears.

Then I minimize the app by pressing device home button.
On open same app from recent apps, I observed that keyboard again appeared even password field is enable=false.

Is there android default behavior? Or We can do something to overcome it.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer which solved your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

first, learn English, then ask. Second, you can do something like editText.setOnFocusListener(). Now, when your editText is in focus, you do this for the keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

when its not in focus you do this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Same thing for u child. Don't be oversmart

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve it by adding a "fake view": try add to your view this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="0px"/>
```

this is a dummy item which gain focus on view startup, you don't need to set anything on it, just add to your view.

Tell me if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"` is activity element. Soft keyboard is made visible every time activity is opened.

Instead of this add to your xml `android:inputType` property for editText.